# Magento: Can't understand uploading images via desktop instead of via FTP client

Tags: image, magento, ftp

I am pretty new to Magento and I had a quick question.

I am struggling to understand how I can upload an image straight from my desktop to my website via the Magento backend without adding it to my FTP client first, and it still show up on other peoples computers when they access the website?

To elaborate on this, in the backend location System/Configuration/GENERAL/Design/HTML Head/Favicon Icon, to add the Favicon Icon you simply search your desktop for the image you want, were with other images, I have to add them to my FTP client first. Why is this and what happens if I were to delete the chosen Favicon Icon off my desktop, would the image still appear on my website?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask this question over at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short (only?) answer: Magento is fairly inconsistent when it comes to administering these specific files. Some options (favicon, email logo, logos for PDFs) can be uploaded directly via form input in System Configuration. Others (such as header logo) cannot.

If I were forced to explain the logic (though I'm not sure it's intentional): favicon, email logos, and PDF logo image assets are not subject to theme design factors such as element layout and CSS. Whereas this is the case though I would think that Magento would not provide the option to change the path for the header logo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That all sounds understandable.

Do you happen to know then what will happen if I were to delete these (favicon, email logo, logos for PDFs) images from my desktop? Does Magento make a copy of the image or something a long those lines, so that if the image does disappear from your desktop it still appears on your site?

Comment: Well, it's for sure that Magento is not serving website users content from your desktop! :-) You can delete these items.